# How to solve this error while creating new Project in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

While creating a new Project in React-Native getting this error in terminal:-

**This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /home/React-Native/TodoList Installing react-native...**

How to overcome this error????

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04

Step 1: Check the node version in terminal.

```
    node --version
```

Step 2: If node version is 16 then uninstall node & npm with below commands:-

```
    uninstall Node - sudo apt-get remove nodejs
    uninstall Node - sudo apt-get remove npm
```

Step 3: Check in terminal Curl is installed or not with below command:-

```
    curl --version
```

Step 4: If curl is not installed then install curl with below command:-

```
    sudo apt install curl
```

Step 5: Then paste the below command in terminal:-

```
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Step 6: Then install nodejs with below command.

```
    sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Step 7: Now create your New Project.